# Gson Json conversion adding extra back slash

Tags: json, gson, backslash

I am working on a service that has the following code (I can change this code):

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("customer", gson.toJson(customer));
anotherServiceClient.dispatch(json.toString());
```

AnotherService Class code has a dispatch method implementation that takes in a String object and adds it to a json where party is a String. I can't change this code.

```
    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    json.addProperty("party", inputCustomerJson);
```

I need the anotherService to have the output like:

```
"party": "{\"customer\":\"{\"id\":\"A123\"}"}
```

but instead it is :

```
"party": "{\"customer\":\"{\\\"id\\\":\\\"A123\\\"}"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

> ```
> json.addProperty("customer", gson.toJson(customer));
> ```

`Gson.toJson` produces a JSON string as output (`"{\"id\":\"A123\"}"`), so when you then later serialize this data again as JSON the backslashes and double quotes are escaped.

Most likely you want to use [`Gson.toJsonTree`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJsonTree(java.lang.Object)) and [`JsonObject.add(String, JsonElement)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html#add(java.lang.String,com.google.gson.JsonElement)):

```java
json.add("customer", gson.toJsonTree(customer));
```